# Using C# client program to read a writing text file in windows 10 with error after running a while

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-10

I am running a C++ API in server side to write a result text file every 2 seconds. And share this file to anther windows 10 and windows xp.

And then I have client side C# program reading the shared text file(read only). It comes out that windows xp working normally while windows 10 will make the server side API can't write the file after running for a while.
The code I use to read file is:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(textFileLocation);
```

And then read line by line. Windows 10 client programwill make the file not writable after running some hours. I also tried to copy the shared file to local first and read the local copied file. Same case still happens.
The code I use to copy file from shared folder:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(textFileLocation, pasteFileLocation, true);
```

Only windows 10 has this issue. 
And mostly tricky thing is that when the server side can't write file, we can't solve it by restart the api. 
We solve it by double click the shared text file in windows 10! Then everything resume. Is there any idea about that?

Comment: I also tried using 
                    System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(textFileLocation,
                                      System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                                      System.IO.FileAccess.Read,
                                      System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite); but still fail

Comment: Can you set the sharing mode on the C++ side as well?  Even when C# has the file open for read, share write, if C++ tries to open for write, **no sharing**, it will fail because there is already a reader.

Comment: I see your point. But windows xp client side with same code doesn't have this issue. Only windows 10 has this issue. And server side api will keep writing the file every 2 seconds. When it start can't writing the file once and it will never able to write file every 2 seconds retry until I double click the shared text file in Windows 10.

Comment: Checked for things that might be different on the new machine, like antivirus, automated backup, search indexing, that might be opening every file that another program accesses?

Comment: Thanks. I check for it now

Comment: there antivirus are the same. I disabled windows10 antivirus but still happening